# C# Collection of Different Generic Types Without Casting

Tags: c#

I've found couple of questions on the same topic here, however I couldn't find what I need. Basically I am searching for this kind of magic:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int DerivedТype { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(T initialValue)
    {
        DerivedТype = 1;
        Property = initialValue;
    }

    public T Property { get; set; }
}

public class OtherDerivedClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public OtherDerivedClass(T initialValue)
    {
        DerivedТype = 2;
        OtherProperty = initialValue;
    }

    public T OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public int OtherProperty2 { get; set; }
    public float OtherProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<BaseClass> baseClassList = new List<BaseClass>();
        baseClassList.Add(new DerivedClass<int>(5));
        baseClassList.Add(new OtherDerivedClass<float>(6));
        foreach (var derived in baseClassList)
        {
            if (derived.DerivedТype == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(derived.Property);
            }
            else if (derived.DerivedТype == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(derived.OtherProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want a list of BaseClass where I can insert instances of DerivedClass and OtherDerivedClass. So far so good.

DerivedClass and OtherDerivedClass hold different properties so I really have no idea how access them. Also I don't want to use any weired casts. So this part of the code prevents me from building.

```
if (derived.DerivedТype == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(derived.Property);
}
else if (derived.DerivedТype == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(derived.OtherProperty);
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `var thisIsFalse = typeof(Base) == typeof(Base<>);`

Comment: Yeah, I guess but the properties may be more than 1. I edited the question ;)

Comment: Good question buddy! Welcome to SO :)

Comment: The object-oriented way to do this is to define a virtual property or method in BaseClass that abstracts the operation you want to perform in the loop. Each derived class would override the method with its own specific implementation.

Comment: I could define a virtual method in the base class that returns a property but what should be its type? Each derived class would return a result with a different type. This means I need a method for each of the properties in the derived classes.

Comment: @KaloyanManev From your example it is seen that it's type should be object. as the only thing you use - is ToString method that belongs to type "object"

Comment: You want to avoid casting, but your class BaseClass and if statements are basically your type checks and casts, just in a different way. You can get rid of BaseClass, make List<object> and check and cast to interfaces with properties you know you are gonna work with. Or go the way as suggested by @MichaelLiu. Or make Lists for each of your derived types (or interfaces) and get rid of these if statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the awesome support! I decided to go simple and just use a cast.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int DataТype { get; set; }

    public object Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataClass<T>
{
    public DataClass(T initialValue)
    {
        Property = initialValue;
    }
    public T Property { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<BaseClass> listBaseClass = new List<BaseClass>();
        BaseClass dummy = new BaseClass();
        dummy.DataТype = 1;
        dummy.Data = new DataClass<int>(50);
        listBaseClass.Add(dummy);
        if (listBaseClass[0].DataТype == 1)
        {
            DataClass<int> casted = (DataClass<int>)listBaseClass[0].Data;     
            Console.WriteLine(casted.Property);
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem that can be solved with polymorphism.  I'll make a version of your app that does exactly what you seem to be doing in your example, but if there was more information as to what your target goal is, the solution may be different.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void DoSomething();
    public abstract void GetData(Dictionary<string,string> container);
}

public class DerivedClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass(T initialValue)
    {
        Property = initialValue;
    }

    public T Property { get; set; }
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Property);
    }

    public override void GetData(Dictionary<string,string> container)
    {
        container.Add(nameof(Property), "{Property}");
    }
}

public class OtherDerivedClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    public OtherDerivedClass(T initialValue)
    {
        OtherProperty = initialValue;
    }

    public T OtherProperty { get; set; }
    public int OtherProperty2 { get; set; }

    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(OtherProperty);
    }

    public override void GetData(Dictionary<string,string> container)
    {
        container.Add(nameof(OtherProperty), "{OtherProperty}");
        container.Add(nameof(OtherProperty2), "{OtherProperty2}");
    }
}
```

Your foreach loop could then be as simple as:

```
foreach(var derived in baseClassList) derived.DoSomething();
```

This is the proper way to do something like this using OO.  There's no need for the DerivedType integer since the object knows what type of class it is and what to do.  This is why one would use polymorphism.  It's simple and elegant and OO.  Extend or change the DoSomething to be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

The OP came up with his own solution, but if the goal is to do something with the data that is more meaningful, you could also pass in an object to an abstract method that allows you to do this.  I added a GetData method that will return all of the property values as strings.  The second type of the dictionary could also be `object` with the actual value stored in the dictionary.

BaseClass could also be a regular class with a method in it to return an IDictionary of `object` values with string keys.  The method could use reflection to get all property values for whatever class it is the base of.  Reflection has much more overhead, though, so is not the most efficient way to do this from an execution standpoint.

The correct way to check if an object is a certain type is to use the `is` operator such as:

```
if(derived is DerivedType<int>)
{
    // Do what you need to do with the specific object type
}
```

If you know you're going to cast the object, as pointed out by Adosi, you would use:

```
var castedValue = derived as DerivedType<int>;
if(castedValue != null)
{
    // Do what you need to do with castedValue
}
```

A null will be returned if the object isn't of type `DerivedType<int>`.  Trying to use (DerivedType)derived would cause an invalid cast exception.

Comment: Thank you for the clean answer! However I need to create something like a get method that return the data not just print it to the console. That's where the problem comes because I don't want to create an abstract method for each property of different type.

Comment: The DoSomething could do that.  How would you like the data?  I can modify my answer to provide that.

Comment: Can you make the DoSomething of type T so it could return the value of the OtherProperty ?

Comment: There is no way you can do something like that without using a cast or a dynamic.  You have to be willing to cast derived to the type it is or do whatever data manipulation you want to do in DoSomething().  The latter is a lot cleaner.  Without knowing what you want to do with the data, it's difficult to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge what you want is between impossible and not a good idea. Typechecking is done at compile time. Stuff like Dynamic can move those checks to runtime, but it results in all kinds of issues (functions that take dynamic parameters also return dynamic).

If you got at least C# 7.0, you can at least write a switch for it. Old switch only supported values vs constants for a few select value types and string. But C# 7.0 introduces [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching). With that you could even use a `is` check as part of a case.

Comment: So, you mean I use "is" to check if the class inside the list is what I need and then somehow cast it to the needed derived class?

Comment: I believe he means like `if (derived is DerivedClass<int>) { ... }` but note this does cast, so you might as well do `var derived2 = derived as DerivedClass<int>; if (derived2 != null) { /* derived2 is a DerivedClass<int> */ }`

Comment: `if (derived is DerivedClass<int>) DerivedClass<int> temp = (DerivedClass<int>)derived;`